# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, json, gson

I am getting a response from a firebase function and dialogflow which hold some information that I need for further implementations.
The response is a JSON, which I hold in `mResultFromDialogFlow`, which is a HashMap (String, Object) type variable.

I've searched other threads like this, but the strange thing was that my problem is at column 2, not 1 and I don't see the problem in the json.
Here is the gson part. The error is thrown on the line with Properties!

```
Gson _gson = new Gson();
String _json = _gson.toJson(mResultFromDialogFlow.get("parameters"));
Properties data = _gson.fromJson(_json, Properties.class);
mTime = data.getProperty("date"); // String type variable
mDateFromUser = data.getProperty("time"); // String type variable
```

This is the response JSON:

```
{"date":"2019-07-19T12:00:00+03:00","time":"2019-07-19T14:00:00+03:00"}
```

Comment: Which `Properties` are you using? `java.util.Properties`?

Comment: So, apparantly, the `_json` has this value:
`"{\"time\":\"2019-07-19T14:00:00+03:00\",\"date\":\"2019-07-19T12:00:00+03:00\"}"`

@MC Emperor, yes

Comment: Have you added the quotes ? or is this the raw value ? Because the object should start with a `{` not a `"`

Comment: That looks like a JSON string converted to JSON. I suspect `mResultFromDialogFlow.get("parameters")` already returns a JSON string. With `toJson()`, you convert a JSON string to JSON. What happens if you try `Properties data = _gson.fromJson(mResultFromDialogFlow.get("parameters"));`?

Comment: @MCEmperor, you were right. I just needed to add `mResultFromDialogFlow` directly to `_gson.fromJson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a JSON string converted to JSON. I suspect mResultFromDialogFlow.get("parameters") already returns a JSON string. With `toJson()`, you convert a JSON string to JSON.

If you try

```
Properties data = _gson.fromJson(mResultFromDialogFlow.get("parameters"), Properties.class);
```

it'll probably work.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I figured it out 1 minute earlier thanks to @MC Emperor

Comment: @DavidBuzatu Well, that's me

Comment: I am too tired, my bad. Thank you again

Comment: @DavidBuzatu You should get some sleep ;-)